# Finding a symmetry in a Lagrangian that is not an ignorable coordinate?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, symmetry

I have particle in a fixed electromagnetic field

$$ E = E_0 \hat y\\ B = B_0 \hat z  $$

The Lagrangian for such a system is:

$$ L = \frac{1}{2} m \dot x^2 + \frac{1}{2} m \dot y^2 + \frac{1}{2} m \dot z^2 + q E_0 y + q \dot x B_0 y $$

The question is asking for "3 symmetries giving 3 conserved quantities" that apparently let you solve the whole system. I see two obvious symmetries: in $x$ and $z$, because they do not appear in the Lagrangian. This means that the cannonical momentum in each of those directions is conserved:

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \frac{dL}{d\dot x} = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad m\dot x + qB_0 y = \text{constant} $$

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \frac{dL}{d \dot z} = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad m \dot z = \text{constant} $$

I could use the Lagrange equation in $y$ to solve the whole system, but it does not seem to be a "conserved quantity". The canonical momentum in $y$ changes as $y$ appears in the Lagrangian.

Is this just bad wording of the question or am I missing something?

Comment: Hint: There is no explicit $t$ dependence.